# PDFA document is missing comments and markings

Tags: itext

I have a pdf document, I open that with adobe acrobat reader and add comments to it, and highlight some content and save the document. When I ask itext to convert this saved pdf to pdfA, I get a pdfa document, but the markings and comments are missing. Can anyone let me know if this can be achieved in any way?

Comment: It is hard to convert ordinary PDF to PDF/A. Are you sure the result is a valid PDF/A document? Maybe there's a blue ribbon on top when opening it in Adobe Reader, but the blue ribbon only indicates that the document *pretends* to be PDF/A compliant; it doesn't mean the document *is* PDF/A compliant. Adobe Reader isn't capable of validating PDF/A, you need Acrobat Pro to do that. This being said: we can't tell you why the annotations went missing because you don't share any code. We don't even know if you're using the new iText 7 or an older, no longer supported version.

Comment: *"When I ask itext to convert this saved pdf to pdfA"* - How do you tell iText to do so? I'm not aware of iText having an explicit single method for that.

Comment: @mkl from the description, I assume that a `PdfAWriter` is created, and that all the pages of the non-PDF/A document are copied to that `PdfAWriter` as `PdfImportedPage` instances. That results in a PDF document with a blue ribbon that thinks it's a PDF/A document, but that probably won't validate as a PDF/A document. Whether this throws an exception or not, will depend on the version of iText that is used. The older, the less likely the OP will notice that the result isn't really PDF/A.

Comment: @BrunoLowagie : I am using iText 5.5.9. And yes I am using PDFAWriter to create the PDFA document by reading the pages of pdf. The PDF that I try to convert to PDFA is also created by iText. There are no errors when the document is converted to PDFA. But I do not understand why the added components like comments and markings are missing. What has PDFA validation got to do with content missing?

Comment: There are two questions: *I do not understand why the added components like comments and markings are missing.* That's explained in [chapter 6 of my book](https://manning-content.s3.amazonaws.com/download/d/3645210-8560-4e6d-9b03-3f9aca1921a5/samplechapter6.pdf). As documented, you are throwing away all interactive features. *What has PDFA validation got to do with content missing?* PDF/A requires you to meet a specific set of requirements that require more effort than just copying pages to a `PdfAWriter`. You are seriously underestimating the problem. Please hire an expert.